# Restart Docker Compose with update to database

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I've been working with a simple MySQL table using Docker Compose that only included ID and NAME column.  I attempted to update my myDb.sql file that initially creates the table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Person` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL, // updated this column
  `lastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL  // added this column
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I updated the NAME column to firstName, and added a lastName column.

I then stopped the Docker containers by running DOCKER-COMPOSE STOP.

I then restarted the Docker containers by running DOCKER-COMPOSE UP.  I even tried DOCKER-COMPOSE RESTART.

The error message I was able to print in the console was this:

```
SELECT '', id, `firstName` From Person<br>Unknown column 'firstName' in 'field list'
```

This leads me to believe that I did not restart Docker Compose correctly.

How do I restart Docker Compose so that it runs the CREATE TABLE command?

### Edit

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
www:
    build: .
    ports: 
        - "8001:80"
    volumes:
        - ./www:/var/www/html/
    links:
        - db
    networks:
        - default
db:
    image: mysql:5.7.13
    ports: 
        - "3306:3306"
    environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: myDb
        MYSQL_USER: user
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
    volumes:
        - ./dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        - persistent:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
        - default
phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links: 
        - db:db
    ports:
        - 8000:80
    environment:
        MYSQL_USER: user
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
volumes:
    persistent:
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM php:7.0.30-apache 
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

Comment: Can you share dockerfile for database ?

Comment: @Prasanth - I've added my docker-compose.yml file and my Dockerfile.

Comment: Did you update your sql file after the database container started running ?

Comment: @Prasanth - Yes.  I altered the sql file.  The column were originally 'id' and 'name'.  I tried to change the column 'name' to 'firstName', and then add a new column called 'lastName'.

Comment: Did the table get created when building the image or when running the image or container ?

Comment: Have you tried the --force-create switch when running docker compose? Refer to the docker-compose up documentation for an explanation of the command. https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/

Comment: You can also try try deleting all containers "docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)" followed by deleting all images "docker rmi $(docker images -q)" if you want to force the containers to be created again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` mechanism only runs the first time a database container starts up, with an empty database.  You'll need to explicitly `docker-compose rm` your containers after you `docker-compose stop` them to cause the current database to be deleted, and then a new empty table will be created in a new empty database.

If you need to preserve the data in an existing database, you are looking for a mechanism called a *migration*.  The various Docker database images don't directly have migration support; this is almost always something that is packaged with your application-level database library (Ruby on Rails and Python's SQLAlchemy both have migration facilities, for instance).

Once you have a migration system anyways, it's probably better to just use that to create the initial database tables.  `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` makes a little more sense for database-level setup like creating initial users or loading a seed database dump, but in practice you will always need a migration system for changes like what you're describing.

Comment: I don't need to preserve the data.  I'm just testing right now, practicing.  I did run the docker-compose rm as you suggested.  I restarted the docker container, but I am receiving the same error.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @JohnBeasley In this case, you have to remove the previously created volume. Note that, your data will be lost.

Answer (score 2):

Do `docker-compose down` whenever you update your schema, it will remove containers and docker network and do `docker-compose up` to bring your environment with your new schema. Hope it helps. If not, try updating to latest mysql image, the image you are using is almost 3 years old.

Comment: I don't think I tried docker-compose down.  All I did was docker-compose stop.  I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: that will not work. You have to remove the volume with MySQL data. So either rm the container or do docker-compose down -v (it will delete the volumes) and then docker-compose up

Answer (score 0):

So I was thinking that restarting docker-compose would automatically run the CREATE TABLE query in the myDb.sql file.  As indicated above, I changed the name of 'name' column to 'firstName' and added a column called 'lastName'.

Again, I am not sure if there was a command that actually does this, but in the end, I was able to alter the table in phpmyadmin.  Once I altered the table there, now I am getting data back to the page with no errors.