# Why are changes to seed sql file ignored when rebuilding docker mysql image with docker compose?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have a minimal example mysql library.

seed.sql:

```
create schema MyDatabase;
use MyDatabase;
create table MyTable(MyNumber int);
insert into MyTable values (70);
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql
COPY *.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Part of my docker-compose.yml:

```
my-database:
  build: my-database
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

Now if I change `70` to `71` in `insert into MyTable values (70);` and run `docker compose up --build -d my-database`, I'd expect a new image to be created with the new seed file.

But instead, the old value of 70 is still in the database (I connect directly using mysql cli to check). I need to run [docker compose rm my-database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56209171/492336) first for my seed.sql changes to take effect.

My question is **why is that**? Shouldn't changes to the seed.sql file cause docker to create a brand new image for my-database, which would force it to completely relaunch the service?

Another similar question - [Scripts in the /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d folder are ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74705161/scripts-in-the-docker-entrypoint-initdb-d-folder-are-ignored)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL scripts in docker-entrypoint-initdb are not executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38504257/mysql-scripts-in-docker-entrypoint-initdb-are-not-executed)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get docker-compose to always re-create containers from fresh images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612650/how-to-get-docker-compose-to-always-re-create-containers-from-fresh-images)

Comment: In your output, do you see `COPY *.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` being re-run or is it cached and this layer skipped by Docker?

Comment: None of the above 2 questions answer WHY this is the case. WHY doesn't a change to the seed.sql file create a brand new image?

Comment: @Justinas - if I make changes to it, how can it be skipped? It would invalidate the caching.

Comment: @sashoalm I have seen when some tools does not update file mtime, so cache depending on that metadata is not cleared

Comment: The data is in an (anonymous) volume, inserted by the base `mysql` image, and since there's already a database the initialization scripts aren't re-run.  For most applications I might prefer using your application framework's database-migration system to doing something Docker-specific.

Comment: @DavidMaze - thank you, that gets closest to answering my actual question so far. So the initdb scripts see the volume and just don't run the sql. But wouldn't the changes to my file build a new docker image? Or do you mean to say that the same anonymous volume gets reused even if the docker image SHA1 has changed?